# Leetcode 3 sum questions

Tags: python

Given an integer array nums, return all the triplets [nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]] such that i != j, i != k, and j != k, and nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0.

Notice that the solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

Example 1:

Input: nums = [-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]
Output: [[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]

I dont undertsand why  [-1, 2, -1], [0, 1, -1] are not counted.
Here is my code, the result  [[-1, 0, 1], [-1, 2, -1], [0, 1, -1]] is the output

```
nums=[-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]
n=len(nums)


finallstnew =[[nums[i],nums[j],nums[k]]  for i in range(n-2) for j in range(i+1,n-1) for k in range(j+1,n) if nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0]

nn=len(finallstnew)
newlist = [ii for nn,ii in enumerate(finallstnew) if ii not in finallstnew[:nn]]#remove the repetitive value that happened before


print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code helps investigate the reason why, by taking a look at what array indices and integers you're working with:

```
x=[-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]
print("array input: ", x)
n=len(x)
print("length of input array:", n)
i = range(n-2)
print("\ni is equal to ", i)
for a in i:
    print("includes x[", a, "] which contains ", x[a])
j = range(len(i)+1,n-1)
print("\nj is equal to ", j)
for b in j:
    print("includes x[", b, "] which contains ", x[b])
k = range(len(j)+1,n)
print("\nk is equal to ", k)
for c in k:
    print("includes x[", c, "] which contains ", x[c])
```

It outputs:

```
array input:  [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]
length of input array: 6

i is equal to  range(0, 4)
includes x[ 0 ] which contains  -1
includes x[ 1 ] which contains  0
includes x[ 2 ] which contains  1
includes x[ 3 ] which contains  2

j is equal to  range(5, 5)

k is equal to  range(1, 6)
includes x[ 1 ] which contains  0
includes x[ 2 ] which contains  1
includes x[ 3 ] which contains  2
includes x[ 4 ] which contains  -1
includes x[ 5 ] which contains  -4
```

One of the reasons why you're getting that answer is that you're performing a two-sum, since j is range(5, 5) which evaluates to an empty list!

There are other issues following this, but this allows you to see where you went wrong. I would recommend also using `len(i)` rather than `i`, since `i, j, k` are of type `<class 'range'>` and you're using them like integers. Learn more how range() and len(range()) work [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-range-function/).